# пишет, что надо обновить pip, хотя он обновлен

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
(venv) C:\Users\135nn\PycharmProjects\Labyrinth>pip install winshell
Requirement already satisfied: winshell in c:\users\135nn\pycharmprojects\labyrinth\venv\lib\site-packages (0.6)
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(venv) C:\Users\135nn\PycharmProjects\Labyrinth>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\135nn\pycharmprojects\labyrinth\venv\lib\site-packages (19.1.1)

(venv) C:\Users\135nn\PycharmProjects\Labyrinth>pip install winshell
Requirement already satisfied: winshell in c:\users\135nn\pycharmprojects\labyrinth\venv\lib\site-packages (0.6)
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Хочу установить winshell, пишет что я пользуюсь версией 10.0.1 и что доступна версия 19.1.1 и её нужно установить по следующей команде.

Ввожу эту команду, пишет что pip уже обновлен до 19.1.1.

Не знаю как исправить и как установить winshell?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
(venv) C:\Users\135nn\PycharmProjects\Labyrinth>pip install win32con
Collecting win32con
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32con (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for win32con
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

также из-за этого я не могу установить win32con

Comment: Версия pip никак не влияет на возможность или невозможность установки

Comment: winshell у вас давным-давно успешно установлен, а win32con просто не существует, а установить что-то несуществующее очевидно невозможно

Comment: Что выдает pip --version ?

Comment: Модуль win32con входит в пакет pywin32, т.е. нужно делать `pip install pywin32`

Comment: Каким-то образом у Вас вызывается pip из основной инсталляции, а не из виртуального окружения. Попробуйте выполнить команду `which pip`. Также, при активированном виртуальном окружении, убедитесь, что у Вас первой строкой в PATH стоит: `c:\users\135nn\pycharmprojects\labyrinth\venv\Scripts`